# Program not proceeding past if statement (Java)

Tags: java

So, this may look like a mess but I just started Java a few hours ago and I was building a program I've had in my head for a while. Currently, it hangs up at the last section where it asks if there were any others in the video. Any idea why this is happening? Starts at bottom with variable yn.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tagger {
  //inputs should include the type of video, who's in it, and what the game is called.
  //Later versions can alter this, including alternate game titles.
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String mod = null;
    String who2 = null;     
    String group = "SmeggCo";

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Actagger! Let's get started.");
    System.out.println("To start, is this a mod spotlight or a Let's Play?");
    String type = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Awesome! A " + type + ", eh? Sounds fun!");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ex){
    }

    System.out.println("What game is it?");
    String game = input.nextLine();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ex){
    }
    System.out.println( game + "? I'll have to check that out!");
    if (type == "mod spotlight"){
        System.out.println("What was the mod's name?");
        mod = input.next();
        System.out.println("Huh, I've never heard of" + mod + ".");
    }

    System.out.println("Alright, last question. Who was in this video?");
    String who = input.next();
    System.out.println(who + " is pretty awesome!");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ex){
    }

    System.out.println("Was anyone else in the vid?");
    String yn = input.next();
    if (yn == "Yes"){
        System.out.println("Who?");
        who2 = input.next();            
        System.out.println("So " + who + " and" + who2 + "? Those two are weirdos!");
        String[] tags = new String[5]; //Setup final array of tags. Will add to this later in 2.0
        tags[0] = type;
        tags[1]=game;
        tags[2]=who;
        tags[3]=who2;
        tags[4]=mod;
        tags[5]=group;
        System.out.println("Here's your tags!");
        System.out.println(tags);
        System.out.println("Does that look right? Good!");
    }
    if (yn == "No"){
        String[] tags = new String[5]; //Setup final array of tags. Will add to this later in 2.0
        tags[0] = type;
        tags[1]=game;
        tags[2]=who;
        tags[3]=who2;
        tags[4]=mod;
        tags[5]=group;
        System.out.println("Here's your tags!");
        System.out.println(tags);
        System.out.println("Does that look right? Good!");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: String comparison is not done using == but should be done with String#equals

Comment: Please don't post a huge block of code and say: "tell me why it behaves this way".  It's a recipe for down votes.  If you must ask questions of this sort, at least break it down to 2 or 3 lines where the program does not behave as you expect, and then ask for clarification on how those lines are supposed to behave.

Comment: I'm sorry for the long block, this was my first post here and I wasn't sure how much people would need.

Answer (score 1):

Your equality testing is wrong. You should use the `equals()` method, not `==`

Comment: You might want to use `equalsIgnoreCase()` instead, so users can input "no", "NO", "No", nO", whatever... :-)

Comment: Thank you so much! I had no clue that method even existed.